# How to produce this symbol in LaTex?

Tags: symbols

[image]

I wonder how to produce this symbol.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you plan to use it only in the text-style and display-style (i.e. no scriptstyle), then you can define:

```
\def\E{{\rm E}\mkern-8mu\raise.42ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle\circ$}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a version that scales well at every font size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\DeclareMathOperator{\EX}{\mathbb{E}}

\makeatletter
% helper command
\newcommand{\srcirc@}[1]{% small raised circ
  \sbox\z@{$#1\mathrm{E}$}%
  \vbox to\ht\z@{%
    \vskip 0pt plus 1.15fil
    \hbox{\scalebox{0.85}{$\m@th#1\circ$}}%
    \vfil
  }%
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Ecirc}{{\mathpalette\Ecirc@\relax}}
\newcommand{\Ecirc@}[2]{%
  \ooalign{$\m@th#1\mathrm{E}$\cr\hfil\srcirc@{#1}\cr}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\Ecirc \scriptstyle \Ecirc \text{\LARGE$\Ecirc$}
\]
\[
\mu_a=\Ecirc Y(a)=\argmin_{v\in\mathcal{W}_2(\mathcal{I})}\EX\{W_2^2(Y(a),v)\},
\qquad a=0,1
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=5886068#5886068

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hey! It works!